# Hint for finding the sum: $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{4n^2-1} x^{2n+1}$?

Tags: summation

I know that $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{4n^2-1}$ is a telescoping sum, but $x^{2n+1}$ in the sum complicates it a bit.

Comment: Try taking the derivative

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The sum is $-x+\dfrac {x^3}3+\dfrac{x^5}{15}+\dfrac{x^7}{35}+\dfrac{x^9}{63}+\cdots+\dfrac{x^{2n+1}}{4n^2-1}+\cdots$.

Its derivative is $-1+x^2+\dfrac{x^4}3+\dfrac{x^6}5+\dfrac{x^8}{7}+\cdots+\dfrac{x^{2n}}{2n-1}+\cdots.$

$=-1+x\left(x+\dfrac{x^3}3+\dfrac{x^5}5+\dfrac {x^7}7+\cdots+\dfrac{x^{2n-1}}{2n-1}+\cdots\right)$

$=-1+x\tanh^{-1}x$.

Can you take it from here?

Comment: Taking $\int_{0}^{X} f'(x) dx$? I haven't really worked with $tanh$ or $arctanh$ before.

Comment: $\tanh x=\dfrac{e^x-e^{-x}}{e^x+e^{-x}}$, so $\tanh^{-1}x=\frac12\ln(1+x)-\frac12\ln(1-x)$

Comment: Thank you very much, now I was able to carry forward.